# Use an external css sheet and a dash bootstrap theme on the same dash app

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I am trying to use a dash bootstrap theme and an external css stylesheet together but i am not sure how to use them together on the external_stylesheets parameter . Any help would be very appreciated.

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SUPERHERO])
```

Answer (score 3):

The `external_stylesheets` argument is a list, i.e. you can add multiple stylesheets. In your case, it would be,

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css", dbc.themes.SUPERHERO]
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```